# Window Code128 font not showing at print

Tags: c#, printing, fonts

I had a Code 128 True Type Font.

[image]

```
        Font font1DText = new Font("Code 128", 16);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("12345", font1DText, Brushes.Black, fInfoStartX , fInfoStartY);
```

I had tried this on Windows 10 and Window 7. The funny thing is initially with Win10 when i print to a printer, it does not show the the barcode which is supposed to be line and spaces. It shows the raw text of the content ie "12345".
At a later stage(i am not sure what i did) it suddenly is able to print correctly.

I now use the same font and code on another PC Win7. The problem happens again showing the raw text "12345"
My purpose of this thread is not about encoding the 128. But why doesn't the print correctly display the 128 font.

Comment: What happended? You wrote all was well now?! I do think you need to enclose the raw text with __start and stop codes__. Your question only shows the raw text, without the start&stop code! See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39263194/c-sharp-code-128-does-not-print-out/39266941#39266941)!   Do note that the `Î` character you enclosed the text with was itself a type of start/stop code, albeit not really the right one..! - And of course the font needs to be installed on each machine..

Comment: Hi Taw. It was working fine in one PC and not on the other, all font was installed too. I believe even without the start,stop character, the print out should still have barcodes except it cannot be scan. For my problem, i think it is not related to the encoding but how VS2012 actually processed the font when sent to printer.

Comment: I don't know how you send it to the printer, but if the same code is used the problem should be with the machine and, most likely, the installed fonts. Re-installing and also double checking their properties to be the same is my advice. Note that there are several free code128 fonts out there with different qualities and properties but very similar names! - Also note my expanded [answer,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39263194/c-sharp-code-128-does-not-print-out/39266941#39266941) which includes a simpkle encoding routine with checksums etc..